# What is the Exact Function to Popup a Window?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window

This is the code for POPUP Box:

```
<?php
$getBtsid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$btsid = substr($getBtsid, 0, -1);
?>

<center>

<?php
conFunc($db); // Connection Function

$congestedsite = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rollout_tracker` WHERE `site_id` LIKE '%".$btsid."'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($congestedsite))
{
    echo "<b>BTS ID:</b> " . $btsid . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Sector ID:</b> " . substr($getBtsid, -1) . "<br />";
}
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo '<a href="javascript:window.close();">CLOSE WINDOW</a>';  
?>
```

And this is how this POPUP BOX is called:

```
echo "<a href=javascript:popcontact('btsdetails.php?uid=" . $row["bs_id"] . "')>" . $row['bs_id'] . "</a>";
```

And my JavaScript Function Goes Below:

```
function popcontact(URL)
{
    var popup_width = 600;
    var popup_height = 400;
    var day = new Date();
    var id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width='+popup_width+',height='+popup_height+'');");
}
```

Though this code is working, but it is somehow effecting my other JavaScript codes.

I am not understanding the reason. PROBABLY, I HAVE MISSED SOMETHING WITHIN THIS CODE.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Please?

Comment: By your own writing, the code is working. What is the problem?

Comment: But for this code other JavaScript codes are not working, so I thought that probably I have done something wrong with this code block! Thats why sharing with everyone to find whether I have done something wrong with this codes or not.

Comment: Well, what is "not working" in the other code? How do you know that something is wrong, and more important why do you think it is this block causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
function OpenCustomerInfo(OrderID) {
    CustomerInfoWin = window.open('customer_details.asp?orderid=' + OrderID, 
    'CustomerInfoWin',
    'width=600, 
     height=300, 
     left=200, 
     top=200, 
     resizable=yes,
     scrollbars=no,
     menubar=yes')

    CustomerInfoWin.focus();
 }
```